# EntityFramework 6 won't work with MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I am trying to use my model and create a database from it. When i try to generate a database based on the model i get the following error:

> Running transformation: System.InvalidOperationException: The SSDL generated by the activity called 'CsdlToSsdlAndMslActivity' is not valid and has the following errors:
>   No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information.
>
> ```
>    at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.DatabaseGeneration.EdmExtension.CreateAndValidateStoreItemCollection(String ssdl, Version targetFrameworkVersion, IDbDependencyResolver resolver, Boolean catchThrowNamingConflicts)
>    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingFED2D73CEED00C99E8A0A14FA9AE33EAFFDF3CAAFEE9E04D21CC913F1C5C88D960592C81A433C11663E61FD5459CF679CFD9B7275B72CA8BFB8D753DBB9FDDE3.GeneratedTextTransformation.get_Store() in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes\GenerateTSQL.Utility.ttinclude:line 57
>    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplatingFED2D73CEED00C99E8A0A14FA9AE33EAFFDF3CAAFEE9E04D21CC913F1C5C88D960592C81A433C11663E61FD5459CF679CFD9B7275B72CA8BFB8D753DBB9FDDE3.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText() in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\DBGen\SSDLToSQL10.tt:line 84     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes\GenerateTSQL.Utility.ttinclude   57
> ```

The following contains my App.config if that is of any help:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SomeDatabase" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="password=user;server=192.168.0.114;uid=hello;database=example;persistsecurityinfo=True;" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"></assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I know the issue is with the `MySql.Data.MySqlClient`based on the error message, but i can't seem to figure out what it wants me to do. I have added `MySql.Data`, `MySql.Data.Entity.EF6` and `EntityFramework` to the project.

Anyone knows how to fix this issue?

Comment: Is your EF code in a different assembly/project to your program's entrypoint? You may need to add an assembly reference to `MySq.Data.MySqlClient` to your entrypoint project and ensure your `App.config` content is in the entrypoint project, not just the library project.

Comment: My EF code is in the same project as my program's entrypoint. The `App.config` is aswell.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem before this. I manage to solve it by creating a whole new project.

1. Go to `Manage NuGet Packages`, install `EntityFramework`, `MySql.ConnectorNET.Data` and `MySql.ConnectorNET.Entity`.
2. Use the connection string as shown here `<add name="SomeDatabase" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="server=localhost;port=3306;database=example;uid=hello;password=user"/>`
3. Add `[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]` in DbContext class.